# ESP32-PICO-MINI

Tags: esp32

I am using GPIO8 (SD_DATA_1) as output (0/1). At power up, it has default value "1" and only after boot (300-400ms), I can set state to "0". How to I set default state to zero, so it doesn't goes to "1" at power up.
I'm using eclipse and eps-idf (wondows).

Comment: It will depend on the exact board, but the default value is typically hardwired (e.g. by pull-ups) and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

> GPIO6-11 and GPIO16-17 are usually connected to the SPI flash and PSRAM integrated on the module and therefore should not be used for other purposes".

Quote from [ESP-IDF ProgrammingGuide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/gpio.html)

Comment: "are usually" and "should not", is not the same as "are" and "must not", so it's not set in stone

Comment: Well, if your board IS using an ESP32 module,  then those pins "are" used by the SPI flash. Have you try some other pins that were not mentioned above and experienced the same phenomenon?